# What the difference between nint vs int?

Tags: c#, integer

I'm curious about the introduction of [nint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/native-integers) for native-sized integers in `C# 9`. Could someone provide a detailed comparison between `int` and `nint`, focusing on their practical differences in usage and behavior?

```
int num1;
nint num2;
```

I'm particularly interested in understanding when it's appropriate to use `nint`?

Comment: If the program is compiled for 32 bits then they are both the same size (32 bits). If the program is compiled for 64 bits then `nint` is 64 bits but `int` is still 32 bits. [This is documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-cyrl-ba/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nint-nuint)

Comment: have  you looked at [nint Struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nint?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`nint` and `nuint` are new keywords to represent value types that map to the already existing `System.IntPtr` and `System.UIntPtr`.

These types are commonly used in interop scenarios, as their size depends on the runtime platform, that is they are 32 bits on 32 bit systems, and 64 bits on 64 bit systems. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.intptr?view=net-5.0#remarks).

On the other hand, `int` maps to the `System.Int32` value type, which is always a 32 bit value, no matter the runtime platform.

Answer (score -6):

nint constants are in the range [ int.MinValue, int.MaxValue ].
int stores a specific value

Comment: Answer and question both are not usefull.